# Join current and next line, then the next line and its successor using sed

Tags: sed

Given the input:

```
1234
5678
9abc
defg
hijk
```

I'd like the output:

```
12345678
56789abc
9abcdefg
defghijk
```

There are lots of examples using sed(1) to joining a pair of lines, then the next pair after that pair and so on.  But I haven't found an example that joins lines 1 with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4, ...

sed(1) solution preferred.  Other options are less interesting - e.g., awk(1), python(1) and perl(1) implementations are fairly easy.  I'm specifically stumped on a successful sed(1) incantation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking another answer (full credit to @aragaer) to handle single line input (and be more portable to bsd sed as well as gnu sed than the original version - **update:** that answer has been edited another way for portability):

```
% cat >> inputfile << eof
12
34
56
eof

% sed -e '1{$p;h;d' -e '}' -e 'x;G;s/\n//' inputfile  # bsd + gnu sed [1]
1234
3456
```

or

```
% cat joinsuccessive.sed
1{
 $p;h;d
}
x;G;s/\n//
% sed -f joinsuccessive.sed inputfile
1234
3456
```

Here's an annotated version.

```
1{                # special case for first line only:
 $p               #  even MORE special case: print current line for input with
                  #  only a single line
 h                # add line 1 to hold space (for joining with successive lines)
 d                # delete pattern space and move to next line (without printing)
}
x                 # for lines 2+, swap pattern space (current line) and hold space
G                 # add newline + hold space (now has current line) to pattern space
                  # (previous line) giving prev line, newline, curr line in pattern
                  # space (and curr line is in hold space)
s/\n//            # remove newline added by G (between lines) before printing the
                  # pattern space
```

[1] bsd sed(1) wants a closing brace to be on a line by itself. Use -e to "build" the script or put the commands in a sed script file (and use -f joinsuccessive.sed).

Answer (score 4):

`sed '1h;1d;x;G;s/\n//'`

I guess it can be done some other way, but this works for me:

```
$ cat in
1234
5678
9abc
defg
hijk
$ sed '1h;1d;x;G;s/\n//' in
12345678
56789abc
9abcdefg
defghijk
```

How it works: we put first line to hold space and that's it for first line. Every line after the first - swap it with hold space, append the new hold space to the old hold space, remove newline.

Comment: Nice! More elegant than mine in any case ;)

Comment: Fails with bsd sed: `sed: 1: "1{h;d};x;G;s/\n//": extra characters at the end of d command`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this with bsd sed.  This version is a lot more efficient for gnu sed than @Benjamin W.'s verison (tested on a file with a million lines).

Comment: From the man page, 'The terminating “}” must be preceded by a newline'.  Building the sed script with -e should do it: `sed -e '1{h;d' -e '}' -e 'x;G;s/\n//'`.

Comment: That's great.  Now how about the degenerate case for an input file of just a single line?

Comment: I added an answer based on yours which has special case handling for single line input.

Answer (score 3):

This does it (now improved, thanks to [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong)'s hint):

```
$ sed -n 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/\1&/;P;D' infile
12345678
56789abc
9abcdefg
defghijk
```

In detail:

```sh
N                 # Append next line to pattern space
s/\n\(.*\)/\1&/   # Make 111\n222 into 111222\n222
P                 # Print up to first newline
D                 # Delete up to first newline
```

The substitution makes these two lines

```
1111
2222
```

which in the pattern space look like `1111\n2222` into

```
11112222
2222
```

and the `P` and `D` print/delete the first line from the pattern space.

Notice that we never hit the bottom of the script (`D` starts a new loop) until the very last line, where `N` can't fetch a new line and *would* just print the last line on its own, if we didn't suppress that with `-n`.

Comment: Perhaps your answer could be changed to `sed -n 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/\1&/;P;D' file` however as you point out  `sed '1h;1d;x;G;s/\n//' file ` seems more elegant.

Comment: The original version fails with bsd sed.  Version 2 works with gnu sed or bsd sed.  Nice.

Comment: @Juan That's because BSD sed makes it hard to insert a newline in a substitution; having the newline embedded in `&` gets around that.

Comment: Indeed.  Just pointing it out.  Thanks for the updated version.